# How to calculate the time complexity for a nested loop where the second limit has the limit at the variable of the first loop

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity

I have a question on a specific nested loop that I found on a video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9TlHvipP5yA minute : 2:45 )

So, this is the nested loop

```
    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < i ; j++){
            Code; // Takes in constant time (1)
        }
    }
```

So I took n for example 5. 
 So, if n = 5 then : 
 i = 0 => j doesn't execute at all ( 0 times executed ) 
 i = 1 => j = 0        ( 1 time executed  ) 
 i = 2 => j = 0 ; 1                ( 2 times executed ) 
 i = 3 => j = 0 ; 1 ; 2            ( 3 times executed ) 
     i = 4 => j = 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3        ( 4 times executed )  
 i = 5 => j = 0 ; 1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4    ( 5 times executed )

So, ***i repeats n times***, and if we look at j, it repeats 0 + 1 + 2
+ 3 + 4 + 5 times, which is 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... n times, so if we use the Gauss Formula *j* repeats ***n*(n+1)/2** times. 
 So, we will have to multiply the time that takes for the code inside the last loop which takes constant time (1) with the times the second loop repeats and then with the times the first loop repeats. 
 That would be 1 * n*(n+1)/2 * n, which is (n^3+n^2)/2, which would be O(n^3). 
 Now here is the problem. In the video it calculates the time needed for the entire thing, as the time for the second loop so it only calculates n*(n+1)/2 and he says that it is O(n^2), which I don't really understand. 
 If I am wrong, can someone explain how to calculate the time complexity of this and how you got there and why ?

Comment: Your calculation is spot on until `That would be 1 * n*(n+1)/2 * n, which is (n^3+n^2)/2, which would be O(n^3).` - where did the extra `n*` come from?

Comment: So you have the first statement that takes in constant time (1), and then you multiply it with the number of times that the second loop repeats which is n*(n+1)/2 and , after that you multiply it with the number of time the first loop repeats, which is n times ( the loop with the *i* variable )

Comment: Or, if you mean at the Gauss Formula n*(n+1)/2, that is the formula, for example if you want to calculate 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + .. + n, that is n*(n+1)/2

Comment: What I meant is, the extra multiplication on `n` for "the number of loop repeats" is redundant. It's already calculated when you sum `1 + 2 + .. + n`, and derive `n(n+1)/2` from it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Shouldn't you always multiply with the number of repetitions of a loop ? If you have a normal nested loop with for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) { for (j = 0 ; j <  n ; j++){ code } }, you should multiply the time that the code in the last loop needs with the number of times that the second loop repeats which is *n* and after that multiply it with the number of times the first loop repeats which is also n.  So this is why we have n^2 which is O(n^2). I don't understand why you would just calculate the number of times the second loop repeats and not care at all about the first one

Answer (score 0):

This code is `O(n^2)` time.

The outer loop runs for O(n). Now the inner loop runs for `O(n)` when `i == n`.

Hence the overall time complexity of the above code is `O(n^2)`